Ubuntu 22.04 - unable to install NPM
I wanted to install npm in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I tried this command sudo apt install npm , but I got this result:

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be
installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  npm : Depends:
node-agent-base but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-aproba but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-cacache but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-chalk but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-cli-table3
Depends: node-colors but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-columnify but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-debug but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-emoji-regex
Depends: node-got but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-graceful-fs but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-gyp but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-https-proxy-agent but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-mkdirp but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-ms but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-normalize-package-data but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-npm-package-arg but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-read-package-json but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-rimraf but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-semver but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-ssri but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-string-width but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-strip-ansi but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-tar but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-validate-npm-package-name but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
Depends: node-write-file-atomic but it is not going to be installed
Depends: nodejs:any (>= 10)
Recommends: node-tap but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Can you help me please, thank you.
